# Dropdown menu which will respond on click another content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this dropdown menu solution. http://jsfiddle.net/ftymhs8s/

I need to hide the one dropdown menu that is displayed when I click on a different line and show dropdown menu of it. I also need the first line dropdown menu to be displayed always when people go to the website.

I hope I correctly described my problem, can you please help me?

```js
// Dropdown Menu
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown, 0);
dropdownArray.forEach(function(el) {
  var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
    menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
    arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

  button.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!menu.hasClass('show')) {
      menu.classList.add('show');
      menu.classList.remove('hide');
      arrow.classList.add('open');
      arrow.classList.remove('close');
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      menu.classList.remove('show');
      menu.classList.add('hide');
      arrow.classList.remove('open');
      arrow.classList.add('close');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
})

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">First Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Second Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Third Menu </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the JavaScript that you tried and failed with on this post. Read on [mcve]

Comment: I canno't include it, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: So you know in the future: click the icon with the brackets:`<>` Anyways I edited your post for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of multiple collapsible elements where only one of them can be open at one time is that of an accordion.  The general idea is to first close all collapsibles then open the one that was selected by user. The following demo exhibits that behavior by [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm).

BTW I noticed that you made a `hasClass`... er Class. That's not necessary, just use: `node.classList.contains('class')`

**Details are commented in the demo**

### Demo

```js
/* Added .main class to parent <ul>
|| By adding the eventListener to the
|| parent of multiple clickable nodes
|| and using e.target property to find
|| the exact node actually clicked, we
|| have just needed the <ul> to listen
|| rather than 3 separate <li>
|| This is part of Event Delagation
*/
var main = document.querySelector('.main');

main.addEventListener('click', accordion, false);

function accordion(e) {

  /* Gather all .dropdown-menu to a NodeList
  || then covert it to an array
  */
  var dropArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu'));

  /* Gather all links in the .dropdown-menus to
  || a NodeList then convert it to an array
  */
  var linxArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a + .dropdown-menu a'));

  /* if the clicked node (e.target) is NOT the
  || node listening for event (e.currentTarget
  || ul.main) then...
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    // Assign e.target to var tgr
    var tgr = e.target;

    /* if tgr has data-toggle attribute...
    || Find tgr next sibling (.dropdown-menu)
    || Iterate through dropArray wth a
    || for...of loop
    || Remove .show and add .hide on
    || each .dropdown-menu in dropArray
    || Then add .show and remove .hide
    || on tgt
    || Finally stop the click event from
    || bubbling, thereby preventing anything
    || else from being triggered.
    */
    if (tgr.hasAttribute('data-toggle')) {

      // Stop <a> from jumping
      e.preventDefault();
      var tgt = tgr.nextElementSibling;
      for (let drop of dropArray) {
        drop.classList.remove('show');
        drop.classList.add('hide');
      }
      tgt.classList.add('show');
      tgt.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      return;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.contain {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main,
section,
article {
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='home' class="container">
  <ul class='main'>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">First Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Second Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#1">Section I</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Section II</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Section III</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Section IV</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Third Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="https://example.com">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com">Example</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <article id='about'>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </article>

  <article id='services'>
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </article>

  <article id='contact'>
    <h2>Contact</h2>
  </article>

  <hr>

  <section id='1'>
    <h2>Section I</h2>
  </section>


  <section id='2'>
    <h2>Section II</h2>
  </section>


  <section id='3'>
    <h2>Section III</h2>
  </section>


  <section id='4'>
    <h2>Section IV</h2>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a hero! :)

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Comment: Hi, I found problem, when I click on expanded content, content is removed. Can you help me with this? Where is problem?

Comment: Hi, are you running just the code in the answer or did you add this code to another page?

Comment: I add this code to another page, but here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ftymhs8s/2/) is same problem, where I click to submenu, is removed but I don't want it.

Comment: Actually I don't think the content is removed, it's because the content of each menu are links. If you click a link, it takes you to a new location, but all of the links in the demo have no destination yet.

Comment: @user7355869 Ok I made the reference to `e.target` more specific, so the behavior for clicks are normalized.